# Read/Write issues C#

Tags: c#, split, streamreader

I've been spending hours of research trying to find a solution that would fit my project but with no luck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace CustomerApplication
{
    public partial class ListAllCustomersForm : Form
    {   // default constructor method

    public ListAllCustomersForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        /* Since this is the first method to be executed
         * call the displayCustomers method to populate
         * the list */


        displayCustomers();
    } // End of constructor

    // okButton Click method
    private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // retrieve hidden form's memory address
        Form myParentForm = CustomerAppStart.getParentForm();
        // now that we have the address use it to display the parent Form
        myParentForm.Show();
        //Finally close this form
        this.Close();
    } // end of okButton Click method
    //display the customers
    public void displayCustomers()
    {


        //format the header in the text box
        customerList.Text = ""; //Clear the textbox
        customerList.AppendText(
        "-------------------------------------------------- \r\n");
        customerList.AppendText(
        "Name Address Zip \r\n");
        customerList.AppendText(
        "-------------------------------------------------- \r\n");
        //local variables
        String name = "";
        String address = "";
        int zip = 0;
        //get all customers
        Customer[] myCustArray = Customer.getAllCustomers();
        //loop thru the array and display all the data


        for (int k = 0; k < myCustArray.Length; k++)
        {

            if (myCustArray[k] != null)
            {
               StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Jake\Documents\college\CIS340\data.csv", true);

                 Writer.Write(myCustArray[k].getCustomerName() + "," + myCustArray[k].getCustomerAddress() + "," + myCustArray[k].getCustomerZip() + ",");
                 Writer.Close();

                 StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jake\Documents\college\CIS340\data.csv");
                 Reader.ReadToEnd();

                //get the customer attributes for this customer
                name = myCustArray[k].getCustomerName();
                address = myCustArray[k].getCustomerAddress();
                zip = myCustArray[k].getCustomerZip();
                //format the data
                name = name.PadRight(20, ' ');
                address = address.PadRight(23, ' ');
                //display it to the textBox
                this.customerList.AppendText(name + " " +
                address + " " + zip + "\r\n");
            }//end if not null

        }//end for loop
    }//end displayCustomers method


} // end of class definition
} // end of namespaces
```

This code allows me to format my Text Box and give the Array I've created headers.  It also allows me to write any user inputs from my "AddCustomerForm.cs" to a .CSV file, which I can check locally and see that the values are added.

The problem I'm having is reading from my .CSV file and displaying the text into my formatted textbox.

No matter what I try, the only output I can ever see is the blank formatted form, unless I've tried adding a new customer during the same debugging session, in which case, it will properly display the user's input in the "AddCustomerForm.cs".

Once again, I'm sorry if this seems like a novice question, and I assure you I've been researching for a while now, but with no definite solution.  I would greatly appreciate any help that anyone could offer.

Comment: Does this method Customer.getAllCustomers(); also read from the same csv file? Were you able to check the contents of your array after this method call ?

Comment: `Reader.ReadToEnd()` returns a string. So what you're doing is reading the file, but the value never gets stored. You need to do something like `String result = Reader.ReadToEnd()`. It's similar to using `PadRight()`, `PadRight()` returns a string and so you've correctly stored that value in `name = name.PadRight()`, so you need to do the same for `Reader.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: You now have a method called `displayCustomers()` that writes to a file. Try to practice 'separation of concerns'.

Comment: I would love to put this into a new method, but I get errors regarding myCustArray, saying it isn't yet defined, so I keep it under displayCustomers(), where I have it defined.  Should I create a new method in the ListAllCustomersForm.cs? And should I put the existing write statement somewhere else? (After the savebtnclick in the AddCustomer Form -- if so -- how?)

Comment: Customer.getAllCustomers(); 

returns  myCustArray

this works when I populate the array using the add customer form, but when I close the application and reload, I can't return the array any longer, there isn't anything to read.  This is where the StringReader needs to come in, to populate the array, but I don't know how to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the result of the Reader.ReadToEnd() call just read it and then get rid of them.

Try reading the lines whith the StreamReader's [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method.

Comment: I just changed 

StreamReader Reader = new 

StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jake\Documents\college\CIS340\data.csv");

Reader.ReadToEnd();

to

StreamReader Reader = new 

StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jake\Documents\college\CIS340\data.csv");

                     Reader.ReadLine();

I still can't see the output from the .csv when I click the list customers button.

Comment: Becouse you are not using the readed line: var line = Reader.ReadLine();

Comment: I just amended:

*StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jake\Documents\college\CIS340\data.csv");
                     Reader.ReadLine();*

to 




*StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jake\Documents\college\CIS340\data.csv");
                     var line = Reader.ReadLine();*

Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes and now you can add the line to the collection/control you want.

Comment: Just to clarify:  I can now add the line 'code' StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jake\Documents\college\CIS340\data.csv");
            var line = Reader.ReadLine(); 'code'

to any method I want?

If so, I've made myself a new method underneath displayCustomers(), called readCustomers(), and placed the line in there.

This still doesn't read the file and display the .CSV to the screen.  

I also still can't move the StreamWriter statement out of the displayCustomers() method into its own.